# Line Chart axises layout

Tags: qliksense

I have a line chart as it is showed bellow.

[image: Line chart photo 1]

How can I make the x-axis showing off all the data (I need the chart to be in small size), for example as it is appear in the preview bar (I mean by preview bar the scrolling bar under the chart to explore the x-axis value, which I highlighted in red in the second photo). In other words, I want to see somehow the whole data of the x-axis in the chart at once without  the preview bar.

[image: Line chart photo 2]

I hope someone have an idea to help me out, and much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that this is a feature, not a bug - as Sense is built to re-size and tailor the view for any screen size you lose control over the minutiae such as what parts of the chart to show.

Sense will always format itself to fit as per predetermined rules in the background.

That being said, the slider at the bottom of the chart displays the entire chart and users can expand the chart to fill the screen. So it might be an idea to instead of trying to fit Sense to your requirements to readjust your users expectations to what Sense can offer.

If you were able to see all the data in such a small chart, it would be unintelligible.

Comment: of course it is a feature not a bug. However, in my case I do not want this feature. 

Actually, as there is no Trellis chart in qlik sense. I used many line chart in one sheet and with set analysis expression to show in every single chart different value dynamically. And as far as I need only to monitor the fluctuation and see which are going to be 100 for example. then in another sheet I can select certain value to study closely (which seems to be in the trellis line charts interesting).

So, do you have an idea how can I apply that?